# Ndepend API get rules from Ndrules file

Tags: c#, .net, ndepend

I am using Ndepend API in my .NET 4.7 project, currently i am writing the rules in my code like this example :

```
 var types = assemblies.ChildTypes()
.Where(x => !x.IsThirdParty && x.IsPublic &&!x.ParentAssembly.Name.EndsWith(".Test"))
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.NbTypesUsingMe).Take(10);
```

I would like to know if it is possible to get the rules into my code directly from the .ndrules file.

I have looked in the Ndepend API documentation i could not find anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far there is no method to load rules from a rule file. However there is a method to load rules from an NDepend project and from the rule files referenced by the project.You can use this NDepend.API extension method.

```
namespace NDepend.Project {
   public static class ExtensionMethodsProject {
      public static IController GetRulesInProjectFileAndInRuleFiles(this IProject project) {
```